# Single Page App w/ Login Page

Tags: javascript, polymer, single-page-application, polymer-1.0

I have been doing some research on this topic but can never find anything super relevant. I am looking to create a single page application using Polymer. I am building this around a REST API that requires authentication to view is resources.

I have all the details with API worked out but I can't seem to figure out how to handle a login page. Basically what is the best way to keep a user from seeing content without being logged into the application?

Obviously the REST API won't allow data to return to the client but how do I go about preventing a user from going into DevTools and changing some boolean values and being able to navigate through all of the pages, and receiving the 401 errors from all of the Ajax requests trying to fire?

I appreciate any help that I can get! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't prevent users from changing stuff in DevTools. Just ensure on the server that the user doesn't get data or isn't able to pass data without being authenticated.

Issue a token when the user passes username and password and on the server allow only what the user assigned to this token is allowed to do.

See for example https://stormpath.com/blog/build-secure-user-interfaces-using-jwts/